# Show a curve $\alpha$ is simple.

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to show if a curve $\alpha(t)=(t,t^2+1,t-1)$ is simple or not.
Here, $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let $t_1,t_2\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $t_1\neq t_2$, and suppose $\alpha(t_1)=\alpha(t_2)$, then $$(t_1,t_1^2+1,t_1-1)=(t_2,t_2^2+1,t_2-1)$$
which implies
$$(t_1=t_2, t_1^2=t_2^2, t_1=t_2)$$

do I have to solve this as a system of equations? I plotted the curve and it is indeed simple (at least for "high" values of $t$). In that case, we use $t_1=t_2$ in the equation $t_1^2=t_2^2$ and we are done.

Comment: You already have $t_1=t_2$ which contradicts $t_1 \neq t_2$ so you're done.

Comment: Of course, can't believe didn't see that, thank you :)

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments, since you already have $t_1=t_2$ which contradicts $t_1≠t_2$ so you're done. Hence the curve $\alpha$ is simple.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but @CyclotomicField wrote it in the comment and I'm waiting him to do it, if he doesn't post it in the next days, I'll select yours of course.

Comment: To follow MSE etiquette, this answer should probably be CW (Community Wiki).

Comment: @IvoTerek what is community wiki exactly? Is it like when someone answer...their name vanishes and community name appears instead of his?